# Delete files/uploads when delete User

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have my Users table (with name, email, password, etc...) and the users can upload pictures, files or videos.

Their pictures are stored in specific path (for example `/myproject/app/public/uploads/01/picture.jpg` )

I wondered if the files uploaded by the users can be deleted when the row of the user is deleted.

The big issue is that I want to delete the data that the users have uploaded when I do `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

I tried this on the migration file `2014_..._create_users_table.php` :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

use File;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
         Schema::drop('users');
         // Deleting ALL the data that the users have uploaded
         $dir = public_path(). "/uploads/";
         File::deleteDirectory($dir, true);
    }
}
```

But I have the following error when I try to execute `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

```
[ErrorException]
The use statement with non-compound name 'File' has no effect
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `use File;` to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File as File;`